# Dividing WPF window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, window

I want to divide my window (wpf) in three columns: left column must be `DockPanel` ( I think `StackPanel` will not work on `Canvas`), the right column should be another `DockPanel` holding a `listbox` and in the middle I need to have a `Canvas`.

This is what I have done and I am having problem with left column since it is not expandable. I need the left column as holder of custom object so that user could drag/drop them on canvas. Please advise.

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Background="LightGray" Margin="5">
   <Expander Header="Controls" Background="Gray" Margin="2" 
             Content="{StaticResource FC}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
             IsExpanded="True" Width="200" />
</DockPanel>

<GridSplitter Focusable="False" Width="2" Background="LightGray"
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>

<lib:MyCanvas x:Name="myCanvas" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"  
         Background="White" AllowDrop="True" 
         Mouse.MouseMove="MyCanvas _MouseMove">
</lib:MyCanvas >
```

Also, what control should be used on the right side so that can hold a listbox?

Comment: It looks like you're missing some XAML, I see a `GridSplitter` but no grid?  If I am to assume there's an outer `Grid` container around all of this, then the answer to the [last] question is you don't need a container, the `Grid` is the container.  If there is another question here, I don't know what it is.

Comment: no I have not used any Gird. I was thinking Grid and Canvas cannot be used together on window. so you are saying I have to embed all of these into a grid?

Comment: would you please give me what it would look like roughly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at various question you have asked, it looks like you are looking at building an application similar to Visual studio. I would suggest you to look at following great series of articles on CodeProject similar to your requirement i.e. having ToolBox, various ToolBox items , a designer, drag & drop items on designer etc. -

WPF Diagram Designer - [Part 4](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24681/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-4), [Part 3](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23871/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-3), [Part 2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23265/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-2), [Part 1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22952/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-1)

You will just have to add a PropertyGrid on the right side and bind your selected ToolBox item in designer with it.

Answer (score 1):

You **can** embed another grid, or canvas, or other kind of container inside of a grid, you don't have to.  But you have a `GridSplitter` so by definition it needs to be placed inside of a `Grid` in order to provide its functionality, otherwise it doesn't do anything.

It sounds like you want to do something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
        <ColumnDeifnition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" /> <!-- whatever size you need here --->
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Background="LightGray" Margin="5" Grid.Column="0">
      <Expander Header="Controls" Background="Gray" Margin="2" 
           Content="{StaticResource FC}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
                  IsExpanded="True" Width="200" />
   </DockPanel>
   <GridSplitter Focusable="False" Width="2" Background="LightGray" Grid.Column="1"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ResizeDirection="Columns"/>

    <lib:MyCanvas x:Name="myCanvas" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"  Grid.Column="2"
         Background="White" AllowDrop="True" 
               Mouse.MouseMove="MyCanvas _MouseMove">
    </lib:MyCanvas >

    <ListBox Grid.Column="3" ... />
</Grid>
```

This layout gives you your 3 columns, the 2nd column is your splitter that lets you resize the first 2 columns (sliding back and forth between them), and your 3rd column is a fixed size.

Comment: I see Grid.Column is zero-based value so I'm assuming ListBox in Grid.Column=3 right?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Grid` with 3 `columns`. For the 1st and 3rd put a `DockPanel` as child.

I think the general rule is don't put others under `canvas`, not the other way round.